What cinema reference did Tony Dinozzo use in this episode to charm his girlfriend?
In order to make my crush's day I want to do something Tony did in an episode of NCIS when he dated this girl who was a doctor, daughter of La Grenouille: he invited her to have a lunch but she was on call. Therefore he came with his car and brought a table with a tablecloth and they had a lunch in the street. She asked him if he was doing this after a film and he answered her no unless she had seen [name of movie].
My question is what was this movie and what was the episode where he did this?

I know what the episode is, and he does name the film, but it's weird because no such movie exists.

@Walt No???!!! I can't believe it! Such a myth ...

Sorry. :( FWIW, it's this episode. He says it's 'Strangers In The Night' with Cary Grant. That's not a thing. So he's either kidding or seriously confused. It could always be from a film, but I'm afraid I can't place it.

I am certain I've seen the movie Tony meant to reference. Though bringing dinner to the busy love interest is not an uncommon plot device.

In Friends Ross did something similar when Rachel had to work late, but that didn't end up well, so probably not the best reference.

@Walt I think you were thinking about "This Is The Night" (1932) in which Cary Grant played rather than  'Strangers In The Night' (1944) in which he didn't unless Dinozzo did a mistake too!

I was just quoting the character, that's what he says in that episode. "Have you ever seen a movie called 'Strangers in the Night', with Cary Grant?"

@Walt So he is seriously confused because Cary Grant never played in that movie if I'm right...

Sounds like the writer made a mistake when writing this dialogue.  Fortunately, one can excuse the plot hole by saying the character made the same mistake. :)
